# How to show progression bar with toc at the bottom of slides in beamer class in latex?

Tags: latex, tex, beamer

I am using beamer class with Boadilla theme. At the bottom there is a bar that contains author name, title and date. Above this bar, I need to show another bar that horizontally contains the table of contents with a highlight on the current section exactly as the vertical one that is shown on the right in Goettingen theme. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
     \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%

}

\begin{document}

\section{Duck}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{Bear}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{Marmot}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{Falcon}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Many Thanks. But the slide number at the bottom right corner disappears by me when I add your code

Comment: @user9514066 If the frame number is missing for this means that your beamer version is outdated. Can you update your tex distribution?

Comment: @user9514066 I've just added a version that should also work with ancient beamer versions

Comment: @user9514066 Nevertheless, please update your tex distribution. I added the `page number in head/foot` template more than two years ago to beamer